# Why are so few countries willing to recognize Abkhazia and South Ossetia as independent states?

Tags: international-law, international, geopolitics, statehood

> However, the role nationalism might have played in the Russia–Georgia
> War of August 2008 has been largely ignored. One of the most
> influential authors on the conflict, Ronald Asmus, did argue that ‘‘by
> the summer of 2008 … an increasingly nationalistic and revisionist
> Russia was … rebelling against a system that it felt no longer met its
> interests and had been imposed on it during a moment of temporary
> weakness.”4 Neither he nor other authors examined this in depth. Yet
> his contention can support a narrative of ‘‘lawless Russian
> nationalism.” **Russia’s recognition of Abkhazia and South Ossetia in
> defiance of Euro-Atlantic positions can be seen as the tipping-point
> when Russia began to substantiate its rhetoric and to export highly
> nationalistic internal values in an attempt to revise the post-Cold
> War order.**

https://demokratizatsiya.pub/archives/19_3_J235073GW31587H1.pdf

Why are so few countries willing to recognize Abkhazia and South Ossetia as independent states? Aside from Russia, there's only a handful of states that are willing to recognize them as independent states. Even pariah states such as Iran and North Korea, who have a good relationship with Russia, are unwilling to do so. What's the political or geopolitical calculus being made here by these countries, especially Iran and North Korea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the territory of these two countries is claimed by Georgia, so recognizing them as independent will get you on bad terms with another recognized country, possibly their friends as well.

Whereas having diplomatic relations with these countries does not offer any tangible benefits. Russia itself didn't, up and until 2008.

Comment: They are not countries. They are territories of Georgia occupied by Russia.

Comment: They sure have government, citizens and armed forces.

Comment: so does Ichkeria

Comment: @wrod It used to, but not anymore.

Comment: of course, it does. openly and overtly.  and just like ichkeria's current government and armed forces, Ossetia's government and armed forces answer directly to Moscow.

Comment: what part of "answer directly to Moscow" sounds like "independent"?

Comment: I's called Republic of Chechnya, and it does not have armed forces of its own. It does have a worrying number of paramilitaries, I have to admit.

Comment: Neither does Ossetia. It answers directly to Moscow.  And so do its armed forces. ["In March 2017, Russian President Vladimir Putin approved a proposal to incorporate Ossetian military units into the Russian army."](https://www.refworld.org/reference/countryrep/mrgi/2016/en/111575).

Comment: That's an interesting twist and it does put South Ossetian statehood into some doubt (I wasn't aware of that).

Answer (score 3):

One additional consideration: many countries are reluctant to recognise breakaway regions in other countries - especially if such breakaway regions are involved in insurgencies, as Abkhazia and South Ossetia were - in case it emboldens any separatist movements within their own borders. Abkhazia and South Ossetia aren't the only such breakaway regions with limited recognition: there are also Northern Cyprus, Western Sahara, and Transnistria.

Regarding Iran and North Korea, North Korea doesn't have any such separatist movements, but Iran does: [the Kurdish separatist movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurdish_separatism_in_Iran), including [a sporadic ongoing conflict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93PJAK_conflict) against the Kurdish nationalist group PJAK (who, admittedly, only seek autonomy within Iran, not full independence). Iran may be wary that recognising Abkhazia and South Ossetia might drive the Kurds to seek recognition as well.

Comment: A lot of countries has recognized Kosovo, though.

Comment: @alamar True - but I note that Iran is not one of them.

Comment: I guess it also doesn't help that the Abkhaz language is not related to any of the ones spoken in any of its bigger neighbors (to the south) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northwest_Caucasian_languages The Abkhaz also seem to be majority Sunni, which probably precludes too many ties with Iran. (True, they use Hamas as a sacrificial pawn, but they save the 'good stuff' for their closer allies...)

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abkhazia#Recognition

It seems to me countries more beholden to Russia than to China do now:

> UN member states
>
> - Russia recognised Abkhazia on 26 August 2008 after the Russo-Georgian War.
> - Nicaragua recognised Abkhazia on 5 September 2008.
> - Venezuela recognised Abkhazia on 10 September 2009.
> - Nauru recognised Abkhazia on 15 December 2009.
> - Syria recognised Abkhazia on 29 May 2018.
>
> Partially recognised and unrecognised territories
>
> - South Ossetia South Ossetia recognised Abkhazia on 17 November 2006.
> - Transnistria Transnistria recognised Abkhazia on 17 November 2006
>
> Former recognition
>
> - Vanuatu recognised Abkhazia on 23 May 2011, but withdrew recognition on 20 May 2013.
> - Tuvalu recognised Abkhazia on 18 September 2011, but withdrew recognition on 31 March 2014.
> - Republic of Artsakh Artsakh recognised Abkhazia on 17 November 2006. Self-proclaimed Republic of Artsakh dissolved in 2023.

China doesn't though and so North Korea insofar seems to have taken that into account.

I'm not sure what the deal is/was with Nauru, Tuvalu, and Vanuatu. [Apparently](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2009/dec/14/nauro-recognises-abkhazia-south-ossetia), Nauru will recognize anyone for a pile of cash/aid, e.g. they recognized Taiwan too in exchange for that--and the unrecognized them for a bigger pile from the PRC. And, wait for it... re-recognized them

> In July 2002, Nauru accepted $130m from China to de-recognise Taiwan only to re-recognise it in 2005 after apparently receiving another, better offer.

Comment: Interestingly Venezuela used to export more oil to Russia than to China. "In 2019, China imported an estimated 292,000 barrels per day from Venezuela, while Russian state oil firm Rosneft imported 503,100 barrels per day, approximately 62% of Venezuela’s total oil exports for the year." https://www.venezuelablog.org/taking-stock-of-chinese-russian-relations-venezuela/ Although it looks like Russia was mostly acting like a middle man there, re-exporting it to India, Turkey etc.

Answer (score -2):

Because their claim of independence is so laughable that any country recognizing it is bound to become a laughing stock.  They are criminal enclaves created by the Russian Federation, which is itself a barely functioning state.

This may seem irrelevant to people who insist that no one ever takes their ego into consideration, but it's not how actual politics work.

**Clout is a currency in politics.**  And becoming a laughing stock amounts to losing that currency.

Just for context, there is [53k people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Ossetia) living in South Ossetia, down from [70k](living there in 1989.  And there is [14k](https://www.refworld.org/reference/countryrep/mrgi/2016/en/111575) South Ossetia living in unoccupied Georgia.

[And](https://www.refworld.org/reference/countryrep/mrgi/2016/en/111575)

> In March 2017, Russian President Vladimir Putin approved a proposal to incorporate Ossetian military units into the Russian army.

Both regions are obvious Russian proxies maintained and supplied by Russia for the purposes of retaining control over the territory of Georgia.

Comment: Abkhazia is a country populated by ethnic Abkhaz speaking Abkhaz language. I'm not sure what's especially laughable about this.

Comment: @alamar it's not a country.  it's a criminal enclave create by Russia for the purposes of keeping control of the tunnel from Russia to Georgia.  And by "criminal" I don't mean its existence is criminal.  I mean it's always functioned as a criminal organization since the dissolution of the USSR.  It was a criminal organization fed by Russia.  It's existence is not a crime. It's a myth.

Comment: The extent of your knowledge is highligted by confusing Abkhazia with South Ossetia - the latter has the tunnel, not the former.

Comment: @alamar really? we are gonna argue about whether i confused the bloods with the crips?  like that matters?  There were criminal organizations kept in business by the Russian federation sprinkling Russian passports for years and arming them.